# Logical right shift in binary search preventing arithmetic overflow

Tags: c, algorithm, search

In a binary search implementation, obviously:

```
mid = (low + high)/2
```

can cause overflow. I have read a lot of documentation (like [this](http://googleresearch.blogspot.com/2006/06/extra-extra-read-all-about-it-nearly.html)) that the following prevents the problem:

```
mid = (low + high) >>> 1
```

However, I did not see a reason why this would work. Can anyone throw some light on this?

Comment: There is no such thing as a "logical right shift" in C (there's no `>>>` operator).

Comment: Thanks guys, that helped. I did see the C equivalent code there but my questions was more to do with why would even that work. But, all your answers helped cleared my doubts.

Comment: Just use the right type. That's what `size_t` was invented for.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no such thing as a "logical right shift" in C (there's no `>>>` operator), so you're probably talking about Java.

This works because `low` and `high` are presumed to be in the range 0 to 2^31-1 (assuming we're talking about `int` here).  The maximum possible value of `low+high` is no greater than than `2^32-2`, and so is representable by an `unsigned int` (if such a thing existed in Java).  Such a thing doesn't exist in Java, so we've now overflowed.  However, the logical shift operator `>>>` treats its operand as if it were unsigned, so this gives the expected result.

Answer (score 3):

`>>>` is the unsigned right shift operator in Java ([ref](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/operators.html)). Since `mid`, `low`, and `high` are signed integers, the addition of `low` and `high` can overflow to a negative value. `>>>` ignores the potential negative-ness of this result and shifts it to the right as if it were an unsigned number (and in Java, there are no unsigned numbers).

In C and C++, this is the equivalent of

```
mid = ((unsigned int)low + (unsigned int)high)) >> 1;
```

(which is explicitly mention in the article you link to).

This ends up being the same as

```
mid = ((unsigned int)low + (unsigned int)high)) / 2;
```

Note that you probably don't want to do it like this. If you're going to be using unsigned values, you should stick with unsigned values and avoid bouncing back and forth between signed and unsigned.

Answer (score 2):

The same link states the reason for using Java's >>> and reason is (low+high) may exceed the maximum value 'mid' can hold:

> In Programming Pearls Bentley says that the analogous line "sets m to
>   the average of l and u, truncated down to the nearest integer." On the
>   face of it, this assertion might appear correct, but it fails for
>   large values of the int variables low and high. Specifically, it fails
>   if the sum of low and high is greater than the maximum positive int
>   value (231 - 1). The sum overflows to a negative value, and the value
>   stays negative when divided by two. In C this causes an array index
>   out of bounds with unpredictable results.

It also states the equivalent operaiton in C:

> ......
>
> In C and C++ (where you don't have the >>> operator), you can do this:
>
> 6:             mid = ((unsigned int)low + (unsigned int)high)) >> 1;

So the solution is to read and understand that article completely.

Answer (score 0):

As is mentioned in other answers that `>>>` is not a `C` operator.

However, if you want to avoid overflow in `C`, you can try this :

```
mid = (high - low)/2 + low;
```